# Problems with Vector within a Struct

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct, tree

I am trying to create a tri-nary tree in C++, It reads a file and creates the tree based on the words it reads. Each node has a character, and then a list of all the words in the file that started with that character, a parent pointer, a left1 pointer, a left2 pointer, and a right pointer.

Right now, my program will build a tree if it only has at most one node of each type (right, left1, left2) But when I try to use recurtion, and add a word to the word vector, it gives me an error saying "Bus Error: core dumped"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;
struct node_t{
    node_t *parent;
    node_t *left1;
    node_t *left2;
    node_t *right;
    char letter;
    vector<string> wordList;
    int lineCount;
};
int buildTree(ifstream &dataFile, node_t *root);
int insertWord(ifstream &dataFile, node_t *parent, char myLetter);
node_t buildRoot(ifstream &dataFile);
string getWord(ifstream& dataFile, node_t& root);


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    //check for valid number of command args
    if(argc !=2 ){
        cout << "Error: invalid amount of arguments. Usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename>\n";
        return 0;
        }
    else{
        ifstream dataFile;
        char *fileName;
        fileName = argv[1];
        strcat(fileName, ".dat");

        //attempt to open file
        dataFile.open(fileName, ios::in);
        if(!dataFile){
             cout << "Error: Cannot open file.\n";
             return 0;
        }
         else{
            node_t root;
            root = buildRoot(dataFile);
            if(root.wordList[0] == "1"){
                return 0;
            }
            else if(buildTree(dataFile, &root) == 1){
                return 0;
            }
            else{
                for(int i = 0; i < root.wordList.size(); i++){
                    cout << root.wordList[i] << " ";
                }
            cout << endl;
                if(root.right != NULL){
                cout << "Right node does not equal null" << endl;
                }
                cout << endl;
                if(root.left1 != NULL){
                cout << "Left1 node does not equal null" << endl;
                }
                cout << endl;
                if(root.left2 != NULL){
                cout << "Left2 node does not equal null" << endl;
                }
                cout << endl;
            dataFile.close();
            }
          return 0;
        }
    }
}

int buildTree(ifstream &dataFile, node_t *root){
    char ch;
    dataFile.get(ch);
    while(!dataFile.eof()){
        while((isspace(ch) || ch == '\n') && !dataFile.eof()){
                if(ch == '\n'){
                root->lineCount++;
            }
            dataFile.get(ch);
            if(dataFile.eof()){
            return 0;
            }
        }
        if(!isalpha(ch)){
            cout << "Error: On line " << root->lineCount << ", " << ch << " is not a letter.";
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            if(insertWord(dataFile, root, ch)== 1){
                return 1;
            }
            dataFile.get(ch);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My next function is really long, so I will just post a part of it:

```
int insertWord(ifstream &dataFile, node_t *root, char ch){

//if the letter node already exists or is equal to the root letter
    if(tolower(ch) == tolower(root->letter)){
        string word;
        string firstLetter = string(1, ch);
        word = firstLetter;
        dataFile.get(ch);
        while(!isspace(ch) && ch != '\n'){
            if(!isalpha(ch)){
                cout << "Error: On line " << root->lineCount << ", " << ch << " is not a letter.";
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                word = word + ch;
                dataFile.get(ch);
            }
        }
        if(ch == '\n'){
            root->lineCount++;
        }
        int wordCheck = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < root->wordList.size(); i++){
            if(root->wordList[i] == word){
                wordCheck = 1;
            }
        }
//***This is where the error occurs in the recursion
        if(wordCheck != 1){
            root->wordList.push_back(word);
        }
            return 0;
    }
//if letter is less than root letter
    if(tolower(ch) < tolower(root->letter)){
    //if there is no left1 node, create and initialize one
        if(root->left1 == NULL){
            node_t left1Node;
            root->left1 = &left1Node;
            left1Node.parent = root;
            left1Node.left1 = NULL;
            left1Node.left2 = NULL;
            left1Node.right = NULL;
            left1Node.letter = ch;
            string firstLetter = string(1, ch);
            left1Node.wordList.push_back(firstLetter);
    //Add word to left1 node
            string word = firstLetter;
            dataFile.get(ch);
            while(!isspace(ch) && ch != '\n'){
                if(!isalpha(ch)){
                    cout << "Error: On line " << root->lineCount << ", " << ch << " is not a letter.";
                    return 1;
                }
                else{
                    word = word + ch;
                    dataFile.get(ch);
                }
            }
            if(ch == '\n'){
                root->lineCount++;
            }
            left1Node.wordList.push_back(word);
            return 0;
        }
    //if there is a left1 but no left 2
        else if(root->left2 == NULL){
    //if new letter is = left1
        if(tolower(ch) == tolower(root->left1->letter)){
            if(insertWord(dataFile,root->left1, ch) == 1){
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

I have been testing it with a file that has "Dog Cat Cake"
So it should create the root node, the left1 node, and then try to add "Cake" to the left one node.
It has problems in the recursion when I try to add the word to the vector.

I'm wondering if there is a problem with my pointers or if I am somehow passing the values wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're storing pointers to local variables (`root->left1 = &left1Node;`). They become invalid as soon as the variable's lifetime ends. You need to use `new`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback! Where exactly should I use new?

Comment: Exactly where you use the line I quoted, and in any other place where you store a pointer that you got using `&`. I would say `root->left1 = new node_t;`, and get rid of `left1Node`.

Comment: What is the advantage of a trinary tree over a binary tree? (just curious)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very dodgy:

```
ifstream dataFile;
char *fileName;
fileName = argv[1];
strcat(fileName, ".dat");

//attempt to open file
dataFile.open(fileName, ios::in);
```

What you are doing is overwriting your program's parameters. That could cause all sorts of hidden problems.

Why not use `std::string` there?

```
std::string fileName = argv[1];
fileName += ".dat";
ifstream dataFile(fileName.c_str()); // no need to say ios::in because its an ifstream()
```

Also, very dangerous, you are assigning the address of automatic variables to your pointers. Automatic variables will be destroyed when they go out of scope.

So here:

```
//if there is no left1 node, create and initialize one
    if(root->left1 == NULL){
        node_t left1Node; // ALERT!! This variable will be destroyed automatically very soon!!!
        root->left1 = &left1Node;
```

You need to create dynamic variables like this:

```
//if there is no left1 node, create and initialize one
    if(root->left1 == NULL){
        root->left1 = new node_t; // dynamically created, YOU decide when to destroy it
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank you so much! That fixed everything!